# Синоним к "в зависимости/зависит от"

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, выбор-слов, синонимы

Можно ли как-то избежать повторения словосочетания "в зависимости от/зависит от" в одном предложении и при этом подобрать синоним, подходящий по смыслу (и с точки зрения разговорной нормы)?

Этот вопрос особенно актуален для меня при переводе с других языков, где у таких конструкций есть синонимы, выраженные синтаксически/лексически, например, с немецкого: "basierend auf", "je nachdem, was" — и их можно использовать в одном предложении.

Comment: Приведите пример (или несколько примеров) предложения(й) на русском.

Comment: >Во время действия таланта воля или выносливость персонажа повышается на X (в зависимости от силы или интеллекта; в зависимости от того, какой из этих параметров выше). Восстанавливает раненому герою здоровье каждую секунду (в зависимости из параметра силы) и лечит раненого героя (в зависимости от расстояния до лекаря)

Comment: Вообще говоря, поскольку это инструкция, то выглядит вполне нормально (в технических текстах повторы слов не режут глаз). Но объяснения сами по себе невнятны; лично я так и не понял из первого предложения, какой параметр от какого зависит. По геймерскому опыту предполагаю, что воля от интеллекта, а выносливость от силы, но из инструкции это неясно. Также неясно, что именно зависит от расстояния до доктора: интенсивность лечения или наличие/отсутствие лечения вообще. То есть одними заменами "в зависимости" на какое-нибудь "обусловлено" текст не прояснить.

Comment: Таким образом, первое предложение я бы предложил исправить так: **Во время действия таланта повышается на X либо воля персонажа (если интеллект выше силы), либо выносливость (если сила выше интеллекта)**. Второе предложение я не могу править, пока точно не пойму его смысл сам.

Comment: дело в том, что я прислал вам сырые предложения, буквально подстрочники. чтобы лучше понять суть, наверное, придётся прочитать немецкоязычный оригинал, чем загружать мне вас не хотелось бы. либо я чуть позже вам поясню детальнее - особенно насчёт первого.

(а по первому хорошее исправление, спасибо. я добавил его в перевод)

Comment: Лучше пояснить детальнее, потому что немецкий я помню только на уровне школы, мне мало что даст оригинал.